# MS Access show only lastest date for each record

Tags: ms-access

I'm fairly new to MS Access, so I hope you can help me with this one:

I have a table with customers, containing customer ID, name adress and other information. It's related to another table containing dates, number and some other fields. It's a one-to-many relationship, so each customer can have multiple dates.

What I want to do is create a report or a query with customer info and only the latest date and corresponding number for each customer, sorted by that number. How would I go about making that happen?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered on SO multiple times. Try search for it instead of just asking yet again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is to create a query, which returns the data from table with dates, grouped by Customer ID and Max(date), then join this query with main table with customer's information.

Comment: How do I add the other field in the table with dates and still only picking the record with the latest date for each customer ID?

Comment: Just join table with dates to customers table. So, you will have 2 tables and one query joined together

Comment: Jeppe -- if you need more clarification, be sure to ask, but for what it's worth I believe this answer is exactly what you need

Comment: This question has been asked and answered on SO multiple times. Don't encurage newbies in beeing lazy and not searching. SO is here to build a database of good answers. When one is asked over and over again the really good answers will become hard to find.